# Combining multiple commands into a single line

Tags: bash

I had a directory named `myname` which was archived in `myname.tar`. Now I want to take `myname.tar`, unarchive it, and delete all the files in the `myname` directory (after unarchiving).

Here are my commands for the above task:

```
find -name deleteme.tar
tar -xvf deleteme.tar
rm -r delete/*
```

These individual commands are working fine, but I need a one-line command, so I tried this:

```
find -name deleteme.tar | tar -xvf deleteme.at | rm -r delete/*
```

I got this error:

```
"rm -r deleteme/*
rm: cannot remove `deleteme/*': No such file or directory "
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing your `|` symbols with `;` instead: `find -name deleteme.tar; tar -xvf deleteme.tar; rm -r delete/*`

Comment: The command sequence doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  It reads like: find tar file, extract tar file, delete extracted contents.  Is the purpose to exercise the hard disk?

Comment: I get the impression the OP is looking for something like `find ... -exec` and not something as simple as `;`.

Answer (score 29):

The symbols you are looking for are called **control operators**. You are using the wrong ones - you need `;` or `&&`.

With `;`, commands are executed in order, and it does not matter if the previous one ended with success or not.

With `&&`, every command that fails will prevent the next ones from executing.

You can read more for example in [8.1. control operators](https://web.archive.org/web/20110913064431/http://www.humbug.in/docs/the-linux-training-book/ch08s01.html)

Comment: http://www.humbug.in/docs/the-linux-training-book/ch08s01.html is a dead link for me.

Answer (score 7):

In case you're using bash, may I suggest you read the man page of bash (`man bash`), and search for "control operator" (<kbd>/control operator</kbd> + <kbd>[Enter]</kbd>).

There, the different functions of things like `|` and `;` are explained.

You might want to look into using `&&` instead of `;`, though. If you do that, you can perform the following functions in that sequence only if the previous one was successful. Meaning, if `find` cannot find your file, it wouldn't try to compress *nothing*:

```
find -name deleteme.tar && tar xvf deleteme.tar && rm -r delete/* || echo "something went wrong" 1>&2
```

Just a minor suggestion, though...