# What is the theoretical upper limit of commands a user can execute in one line?

Tags: command-line

## Preface

Not sure if this question is within scope of the Unix Stack exchange since it is theoretical in nature. I am willing to move it to a different stack exchange.

## Context

In the Unix command prompt, a user can type [`;`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47758/287201) to execute multiple commands in order. If one fails, it will not stop the execution of the next command.

## Question

What is the theoretical limit to the number of commands a user can chain together in one prompt execution with `;`?

Comment: What is the results of `getconf ARG_MAX`?

Comment: I'd presume it's as many as can fit in the command buffer.  The python statements `print ('ls foo.txt;'*2000)` generated a line with 2,000 commands, and they all ran just fine.

Comment: Which shell? Which OS?

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit) which is a little more expansive on how ARG_MAX works. This link is specifically for Linux, your mileage may vary on Unix OSes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *theoretical* limit on the number of *commands* that the shell (assuming `sh` here) can take on a single line is [defined in the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sh.html):

> The input file shall be a text file, **except that line lengths shall be unlimited**. If the input file consists solely of zero or more blank lines and comments, `sh` shall exit with a zero exit status.

This means that the shell should be able to accept *any* number of commands on a single line, as long as each individual command is short enough not to be longer than what the [`execve()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/execve.html) accepts (the length of a single command, with arguments, and the current environment's environment variables and their values, in total, must be less than `ARG_MAX` bytes).

In practice, this is restricted by the memory resource limits imposed on the shell process.